# Cannot run Protractor Cucumber Tests in headless chrome

Tags: google-chrome, protractor, cucumber, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

I am using the protractor-cucumber framework for UI Testing. This runs fine in chrome, however when running in headless chrome my tests fail with an error message.

Is it possible to run protractor-cucumber in headless chrome? If so, how can i stop the below error message and get my tests to run successfully. I don't understand why it runs fine when chrome is not headless.

Versions I am using:
Protractor:5.2.2
selenium:3.8.1
WebDriver: 12.0.6
ChromeDriver:2.35
Chrome Browser:62.0

I have included my conf.js file below

**Error Message when running in headless chrome:**

> Scenario: :: navigate to BMK page and select a date for the previous month
>       [15:47:41] E/protractor - Could not find Angular on page http://localhost/ : retri                                              es looking for angular exceeded
>       [15:47:41] E/launcher - Angular could not be found on the page http://localhost/.I                                                    f this is not an Angular application, you may need to turn off waiting for Angul                                                              ar.
>                                 Please see
>                                 https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs                 /timeouts.md#waiting-for-angular-on-page-load
>       [15:47:41] E/launcher - Error: Angular could not be found on the page http://ah-                                                        test/.If this is not an Angular application, you may need to turn off waiting fo                                                             r Angular.
>       [15:47:41] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199

**Conf.js**

```
//protractor.conf.js
exports.config = {
    //seleniumAddress: 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    getPageTimeout: 80000,
    allScriptsTimeout:  5000000,
    framework: 'custom',
    // path relative to the current config file
    frameworkPath: './index.js',
    //frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        'chromeOptions': {
            useAutomationExtension: false,
            args: [ "--headless","--disable-gpu","--window-size=800x600"],

        }

    },
    //directConnect: true,

useAllAngular2AppRoots: true,
// Spec patterns are relative to this directory.
specs: ['Features/*.feature'],

baseURL: 'http://ah-test/',

 //  onPrepare: function () {
   // browser.manage().window().maximize();
//},

cucumberOpts: {
    format: ['json:reports/reports.json', 'pretty'],
    require: 'Features/step_definitions/*.js',
    //require: 'Features/step_definitions/hooks/hooks.js',
    tags: false,
   // format: 'pretty',
    profile: false,
    'no-source': true,
},
```

Comment: from the error message, it said the page `http://localhost` is not an AngularJS page,  and you not set `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true` before  `browser.get('http://localhost')`, so protractor will regard the opening page is an AngualrJS page, but Protractor not fine the `window.angular`.  Did your application run on `htttp://localhost`?    If you run script for headless  and headful from different folder, please use comapre tool to check tow folder files are same or not, so that we can know why script run pass with headful

Answer (score 1):

This line we need in our config file in onPrepare method or before browser.get we used in our test files or step definition files.
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;

```
 onPrepare: () => {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    //browser.manage().window().setSize(1640,920);
    browser.manage().window().maximize();
    Reporter.createDirectory(jsonReports);
}
```

If you will get a blank screen when you run in headless then you need to add lines in capabilities , this line is for headless-  args: [ "--headless","--disable-gpu","--window-size=800x600"] and this line is for ssl or https enabled sites- acceptInsecureCerts : true,

```
 capabilities: {
    browserName: "chrome",
    acceptInsecureCerts : true,
    'chromeOptions': {
        useAutomationExtension: false,
        args: [ "--headless","--disable-gpu","--window-size=800x600"]
    }
},
```

You can ask any protractor related question from me.
Thanks